# Problema con el input type search en navegador Mozilla

Tags: html5, entrada, firefox

Estaba hacienda unas pruebas con el tag `<input type="search"…>` en **HTML5** en mi página web y que funciona perfecto. Sólo hay un pequeño detalle y que lo vi únicamente en el navegador *Mozilla Firefox* (no así en *Chrome*, *IE/Edge* o *Opera*).

Pasa que al visualizar este campo de texto y escribir la frase a buscar en el campo, en *Firefox* no aparece la **"X"** a la derecha para borrar el contenido que se puso en la caja de texto. Pensaba que el problema era sólo mío, pero se me dio por probar que pasaba con los campos de búsqueda de los buscadores (*Google* y *Bing*) y fue lo mismo dicha **"X"** tampoco aparece.

Pueden probarlo ustedes mismos (si tienen el *Firefox* y compararlo con otro). Alguien sabe el porqué de este pequeño detalle en el navegador de *Mozilla*. No creo que falte algún atributo o haya que agregar algún estilo en particular.

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar la [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_search.asp) para ver que versiones de navegador soportan las etiquetas que estas usando por ejemplo hace poco me sucedió que en una versión de Safari de un cliente no era compatible la etiqueta `<input type="date">` y también se debe un poco a como lo interpreta cada navegador espero haber contestado tu duda.

Comment: No sé, además yo aca tengo la última versíón (63.0.3) de 64 bits. ¿A ti te funciona en Firefox o no lo has probado? ¿Te aparece esa "X" que comentaba?

Comment: Ahora se me ocurrió entrar a Yahoo y hacer uso de su buscador, siempre todo vía Firefox, y la sorpresa fue que este **si muestra dicha "X"** para borrar el contenido ingresado. Cada vez entiendo menos.